# Getting the IDs of a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have made a custom post 'case studies' which has a number of posts.

I wish to get the IDs of each of these posts to manipulate the data, but despite looking at similar threads, I cannot piece together a way to achieve this. Something like;

```
foreach post oftype custom, get the id
```

I am making a function to display this information in the back end, here is the snippet below.

```
function display_meta_box( $case_study ) 
{
    if (in_array('case_studies', get_post_types()))
    {
        ...get the IDs of all posts of type 'case_studies'...
    }
    ...do other stuff with IDs...
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the basis of the answer buried in the codex

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'case_studies');

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_ID();
endwhile;
```

Comment: You don't need `echo` with `the_title()` and you can also use `the_ID()` instead of `echo get_the_id()`.

Comment: 'basis' - merely showing as an example

Comment: Notice the difference between `the_*` vs `get_the_*` functions. In most cases  it's like `echo` vs `return`.

Comment: Interestingly, for my case, I needed to use get_the_* to manipulate the information in the while loop.

Comment: [set `fields` to `ids` in your query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Return_Fields_Parameter) and you'll get back just an array of IDs, and will use significantly less memory. you also probably want to set `posts_per_page` to `-1` to get all of your posts.

Comment: @Milo Thanks but in this case I actually need the titles of each custom post returned. If I returned ids and then used get_the_title(id) would performance be any better than the current implementation?

Comment: Set `post_status` to `any` if you want to get drafts or other non-published posts. As @Milo mentioned, I also set `posts_per_page` to `-1` to get all posts.

Answer (score 12):

You can get a simple array of CPT IDs by using `get_posts` with the `fields` parameter.

```
$all_post_ids = get_posts(array(
    'fields'          => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'post_type' => 'case_studies'
));
```