# How to hide CPT files from media library programmatically

Tags: custom-post-types, uploads, media-library

We have created a CPT which allows our customer to upload files from the admin page to a folder outside of the wp-content/uploads folder. Files are uploaded and manipulated using wp_handle_upload and wp_insert_attachment.

How do we prevent these files from showing in the media library? Can we filter by post type?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**UPDATE:** here's the code we've implemented so far. New uploads are still not showing in the media library.

```
/*FORCE LIST VIEW IN MEDIA LIBRARY*/
add_action('admin_init', function() {
    $_GET['mode'] = 'list';
}, 100);

/*HIDE GRID BUTTON IN MEDIA LIBRARY*/
add_action('admin_head', function() {
    $css = '<style type="text/css">
        .view-switch .view-grid {
            display: none;
        }
    <style>';
    echo $css;
});

/*REGISTER CUSTOM TAXONOMY*/
function create_hidden_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'hidden_taxonomy',
        'attachment',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Hidden Taxonomy' ),
            'public' => false,
            'rewrite' => false,
            'hierarchical' => false,
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_hidden_taxonomy' );

/*CHECK IF PARENT POST TYPE IS ASSET. IF NOT ADD 'show_in_media_library' TERM*/
function assets_add_term( $post_id, \WP_Post $p, $update ) {

    if ( 'attachment' !== $p->post_type ) {
        error_log("fail1");            
        return;
    }
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        error_log("fail2");            
        return;
    }
    if ( $post->post_parent ) {
        $excluded_types = array( 'assets' );
        if ( in_array( get_post_type( $p->post_parent ), $excluded_types ) ) {
        error_log("fail3");                
        return;
        }
    }
    $result = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'show_in_media_library', 'hidden_taxonomy', false );
    if ( !is_array( $result ) || is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
        error_log("fail4");
    }else{
        error_log("it worked!");
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'assets_add_term', 10, 2 );

/*HIDE MEDIA WITH CPT ASSETS FROM MEDIA LIBRARY*/
function assets_load_media() {
   add_action('pre_get_posts','assets_hide_media',10,1);
}
add_action( 'load-upload.php' , 'assets_load_media' );

function assets_hide_media($query){
    global $pagenow;

// there is no need to check for update.php as we are already hooking to it, but anyway
    if( 'upload.php' != $pagenow  || !is_admin())
        return;

    if(is_main_query()){
        $excluded_cpt_ids = get_posts('post_type=assets&posts_per_page=-1&fields=ids');
        $query->set('post_parent__not_in', $excluded_cpt_ids);
        //$query->set('hidden_taxonomy', 'show_in_media_library' );
    }

    return $query;
}

/*HIDE MEDIA WITH CPT ASSETS FROM MEDIA LIBRARY MODAL*/
function assets_hide_media_modal( $query = array() ){
    $query['post_parent__not_in'] = $excluded_cpt_ids;
    return $query;
}
add_action('ajax_query_attachments_args','assets_hide_media_modal',10,1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Media items are just like posts with **`post_type = attachment`** and **`post_status = inherit`**.

when we are on `upload.php` page, we have two views:

- List View
- Grid View

Grid view is populated via JavaScript and list view is extending normal **`WP_List_Table`**.

Since it (List view) is using normal post query we can use **`pre_get_posts`** to alter the query to hide required media items.

> How do we prevent these files from showing in the media library?
> Can
>   we filter by post type?

We can't just filter the media items by `post_type` since media items post_type is `attachment`. What you want is to filter media items by their **`post_parent's`** post ids.

```
add_action( 'load-upload.php' , 'wp_231165_load_media' );
function wp_231165_load_media() {
   add_action('pre_get_posts','wp_231165_hide_media',10,1);
}

function wp_231165_hide_media($query){
    global $pagenow;

// there is no need to check for update.php as we are already hooking to it, but anyway
    if( 'upload.php' != $pagenow  || !is_admin())
        return;

    if(is_main_query()){
        $excluded_cpt_ids = array();//find a way to get all cpt post ids
        $query->set('post_parent__not_in', $excluded_cpt_ids);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Check [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165900/getting-the-ids-of-a-custom-post-type/165916) to get id's of a certain post type.

As @tomjnowell pointed out it works for list view but it's an expensive query.

One thing you can do is that add some meta value while uploading and query against that meta value

Comment: This will work, but it's expensive due to the `not_in` part

Comment: Yes and it also doesn't work with grid view.

Comment: Thanks bravokeyl. We're trying to implement your and Tom's code but still having problems getting the hidden taxonomy to work (see above). Your post_parent_not_in gave us a 500 server error. I'm guessing the query is causing to it crash.

Comment: BTW it's `post_parent__not_in` check two underscores after parent

Comment: Thanks bravokeyl. post_parent__not_in was correct in the code! Have updated my question with the my current code. New uploads still not showing.

Comment: @bravokeyl: Adapted your script to work with the media library modal popup as well (see edit)

Answer (score 5):

When you create an attachment, do the following:

- If attachments parent ID is for a post with an excluded post type, do nothing
- If it isn't in the list of excluded post types, assign it a tag in a hidden custom taxonomy

e.g.

```
function create_hidden_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'hidden_taxonomy',
        'attachment',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Hidden Attachment Taxonomy' ),
            'public' => false, // it's hidden!
            'rewrite' => false,
            'hierarchical' => false,
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_hidden_taxonomy' );

function tomjn_add_term( $post_id, \WP_Post $p, $update ) {

    if ( 'attachment' !== $p->post_type ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( $p->post_parent ) {
        $excluded_types = array( 'example_post_type', 'other_post_type' );
        if ( in_array( get_post_type( $p->post_parent ), $excluded_types ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }
    $result = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'show_in_media_library', 'hidden_taxonomy', false );
    if ( !is_array( $result ) || is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
        wp_die( "Error setting up terms") ;
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'tomjn_add_term', 10, 3 );
```

Now, take the code in bravokeyls answer and instead of using `post_parent__not_in`, search for the tag in the hidden custom taxonomy:

```
/**
 * Only show attachments tagged as show_in_media_library
 **/
function assets_hide_media( \WP_Query $query ){
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }
    global $pagenow;
    if ( 'upload.php' != $pagenow && 'media-upload.php' != $pagenow ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('hidden_taxonomy', 'show_in_media_library' );
    }

    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts' , 'assets_hide_media' );
```

This should have a significant performance boost and scale better than using `post_parent__not_in`, and provides a taxonomy you can use to filter on other things

This leaves you with one final problem. Attachments will only show if they have this term, but what about all the attachments you've already uploaded? We need to go back and add the term to those. To do this you would run a piece of code such as this once:

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'nopaging' => true,
) );

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    global $post;
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();

        $post_id = get_the_ID();

        $excluded_types = array( 'example_post_type', 'other_post_type' );
        if ( $post->post_parent ) {
            if ( in_array( get_post_type( $post->post_parent ), $excluded_types ) ) {
                echo "Skipping ".intval( $post_id )." ".esc_html( get_the_title() )."\n";
                continue;
            }
        }
        echo "Setting term for ".intval( $post_id )." ".esc_html( get_the_title() )."\n";
        $result = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'show_in_media_library', 'hidden_taxonomy', false );
        if ( !is_array( $result ) || is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
            echo "Error setting up terms";
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    echo "No attachments found!\n";
}
```

I would recommend running this as a WP CLI command, especially if you have a lot of attachments that need processing

Comment: Thanks Tom. We have created a hidden taxonomy using the following but now there are no media files showing in the media library: function create_hidden_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'hidden_taxonomy',
        'assets',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Hidden_Taxonomy' ),
            'public' => false,
            'rewrite' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_hidden_taxonomy' );

Comment: Keep in mind that the hook on save_post only adds the tag to show the post in media on save. Anything that isn't tagged will not show, aka all the stuff you uploaded prior to adding that code. Try removing the filtering code, and keeping the save hook, and going into each attachment and updating it. Alternatively, query every attachment, and run the check on its post parent, and add the term in a loop

Comment: @RichardTinkler I've added a piece of code that will go through and add the term to all attachments that need it retroactively, and a minor modification to the save hook so that attachments that have no parent are now included

Comment: Thanks Tom. New uploads still not showing. Perhaps I am registering the custom taxonomy wrongly?

Comment: Possibly, I see your custom taxonomy is being used for posts, it should be registered to the `attachment` post type instead. I've updated the code examples, so that the loop tells you what it's doing, I've also included taxonomy registration. You don't need to use the `add_action( 'load-upload.php' , 'assets_load_media' );`, you can just do the pre_get_posts filter addition directly

Comment: Thanks Tom for all your help so far. Still having problems getting this to work. I have a feeling the hidden atttachment taxonomy is not being assigned to non-'assets' CPT uploads. Do you know which table in the DB I should check to see if the wp_set_object_terms is really working?

Comment: I also noticed that the hidden_taxonomy is not showing up in WP's term_taxonomy table. Is there something wrong with the taxonomy registration?

Comment: Did you change the way you register the taxonomy? The hidden taxonomy is for attachments, but your questions code indicates it's being given to `posts` which isn't a post type. You want it on `attachment` as those are what are being shown in the media library, not your custom assets post type

Comment: Also, my last code edit with the check for `if ( $post->parent )` should have handled that. Can you place error_log("it worked!"); just after `wp_set_object_terms` then check your error log?

Comment: I've adjusted the query in the last snippet to include a `post_status`, the output of that code is important as it tells you if `wp_set_object_terms` ran or not, and which posts it thinks it ran on, aka the ones you need to check. I've adjusted the code to detect if `wp_set_object_terms` fails. If this doesn't produce output that's useful or the desired result, I'm going to need a lot more information, not from the database tables, but specifically which pieces of code are running and which aren't? Does it return before the function's called? wp_die, error_log, and debuggers are your friend

Comment: Thanks Tom. I've tried debugging your script and have come up with the following: 1.error_log() doesn't write anything to wp-content/debug.log EVEN WHEN I add an else clause to your new if statement. Also doesn't write anything when I add an error_log() to the return statements; 2.when I change the hook from save_post to add_attachment, the error_log() contains error messages. I'm aware that your script won't work with add_attachment but I get the feeling that save_post isn't doing anything. Is this the right hook to be using when uploading a file in the media library?

Comment: there is a typo in the first snippet which uses `$post` but the variable is just `$p`

Comment: This is a great answer with some quality code. It is just missing the code to [filter the gridview of media library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49256599/how-to-restrict-media-library-grid-view-to-only-display-files-from-categories-cu).

Comment: Another note is that using the wp query set() with the taxonomy name directly is now deprecated since 3.1, you should [use tax_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) instead.

Comment: @rtpHarry do you have a link to that deprecation?

Comment: That [link in the comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) says this `{tax} (string) – use taxonomy slug. (Deprecated since version 3.1 in favor of ‘tax_query‘).`

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'ajax_query_attachments_args' , 'custom_ajax_query_attachments_args' );

function custom_ajax_query_attachments_args( $query ) {

    if( $query['post_type'] != 'attachment' ) {

        return $query;

    }


    $posts = get_posts([
      'post_type' => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'numberposts' => -1
    ]);

    foreach($posts as $post){

        $excluded_cpt_ids[] = $post->ID;
    }  

    $query['post_parent__not_in'] = $excluded_cpt_ids;

    return $query;

}
```